# twitter bootstrap html-structure css bug?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, typo3

I have a problem with Bootstrap. I want to combine a typo3 template with a fluid html structure.

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<a name="Content-ce156"></a>
<section class="span6">
<header>contentheader</header>
<article>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</article>
</section>
<a name="Content2-ce156"></a>
<section class="span6">
<header>contentheader2</header>
<article>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</article>
</section>
</div>
```

the second section breaks to a new line, but if i delete the first anchor it works. 
I already try to make the anchor `display:none` or add the class `.span0` for the selector

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]
```

does anybody else already solved this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "it works?" You don't want it to break to a new line even when you include both anchors?

Comment: thats right. I dont want to break the second section to a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links need to be inside the `.span6` elements:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <section class="span6">
        <a name="Content-ce156"></a>
        <header>contentheader</header>
        <article>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</article>
    </section>
    <section class="span6">
        <a name="Content2-ce156"></a>
        <header>contentheader2</header>
        <article>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</article>
    </section>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/S79rh/

Comment: I already find this solution, but is it possibile to fix this issue with plain css?

Comment: for sure, but how i can fix it without changing the html structur?

Comment: You can't, you need to physically move the anchors. You could move them with JavaScript but that would seem like a lot of effort for a small html change.

Comment: <a name=""> is not allowed since html5. Using id="Content-ce156" on the section container also works.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed this problem by deleting the innerwrap of my contentelement and use the outerwrap for the span. than the anker is inside the span like @chrx even wrote. but i dont even know if this is a bootstrap bug, or a feature ....